# What is happening or what happens in this sentence

Tags: present-tense, progressive-aspect

As I heard too many times , people use this sentence

"we will see what happens "

Shouldn't it be "we will see what is happening" ? Because the thing to happen is simultaneous with the verb 'seeing' and a temporary thing.

Answer (score 2):

When people say things like *We'll see what happens* or *We'll see what he does* or *We'll see how they respond*, the context is usually some decision which has just been reached or some plan of action—or inaction!—to be initiated in the immediate future; and the *see* is less about watching future consequences as they unfold but about the 'ultimate' consequences, the state which results from future events.

> We'll see what happens. If the situation changes we can consider a new policy.

The simple present with future reference thus has something like perfective aspect, like a simple past or a 'historical' present.

A present progressive with future reference is employed only in situations where you're speaking about an 'imperfective' future situation:

> We haven't decided what we're going to do for her birthday. We'll see what's happening that night, and pick an event she enjoys.

Answer (score 2):

- *"we will see what happens "* This is used to talk about what will happen after this point with a focus on accomplishments of that action
- *"we will see what is happening"* This is used to talk about what will happen after this point with a focus on an action in progress.
  .